# Using tryCatch to populate a data.frame inside a loop... nicely

Tags: r, loops

I'm a newcomer to using tryCatch. The examples I've seen [here](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912) and on [hadley's website](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#condition-handling)  are a bit over my head (or sometimes seem deceivingly simple!). I've figured out a solution using tryCatch and an if/else statement, but I feel like this might have been possible using just tryCatch, or something more elegant.

Can anyone tell me whether there is a better way of doing this?

I created a toy dataset to illustrate my problem. I also have a feeling the way I'm adding results onto my "final" data.frame might be clunky too.. if there is a way to clean this up, please let me know!

In my example, I try fitting a simple model that "fails" when all of my x-variables are negative, since I'm relating y to the log of x. I want to store the results in a data.frame I'll analyze later.

#### dataset

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 1, 3, 6), 
y = c(rep(c(1:5), 2), c(4, 5, 6)), 
group = c(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5), c("c", "c", "c")))
```

#### These are the groups in the data I'll loop through

```
 groups <- unique(df$group)
    for (i in 1:3){
      sampledf <- df[df$group == groups[i],]
```

#### Catch the error

```
mod1 <- tryCatch(lm(y ~ log(x), data = sampledf), 
                   error = function(e) print("error - no estimates"))
  if (class(mod1) == "lm") {intercept <- coef(mod1)[1]; r2 <- summary(mod1)$r.squared
  } else {intercept <- NA; r2 <- NA}
```

#### store results in a dataframe - get model info when available, otherwise fill with NAs

```
results <- data.frame(group = groups[i],
                        intercept = intercept,
                        r2 = r2)
  if (i == 1) {final <- results}
  else {final <- rbind(final, results)}
}
```

#### The resulting data.frame with model info:

```
             group intercept        r2
(Intercept)      a 0.6813487 0.9473246
2                b        NA        NA
(Intercept)1     c 3.9426178 0.9832168
```

All the script in one place:

```
# make a data.frame of example data
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 1, 3, 6), y = c(rep(c(1:5), 2), c(4, 5, 6)), group = c(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5), c("c", "c", "c")))

# what are the unique groups in the data I'll loop through
groups <- unique(df$group)
for (i in 1:3){
  sampledf <- df[df$group == groups[i],]
  # Catch the error where y is related to the log of negative numbers
  mod1 <- tryCatch(lm(y ~ log(x), data = sampledf), 
                   error = function(e) print("error - no estimates"))
  if (class(mod1) == "lm") {intercept <- coef(mod1)[1]; r2 <- summary(mod1)$r.squared
  } else {intercept <- NA; r2 <- NA}
  #store results in a dataframe
  results <- data.frame(group = groups[i],
                        intercept = intercept,
                        r2 = r2)
  if (i == 1) {final <- results}
  else {final <- rbind(final, results)}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the same idea but bypassing your `if` statement, and put together in a slightly more idiomatic way, you could do:

```
groups <- unique(df$group)
final <- do.call("rbind", lapply(groups, function(grp) {
  sampledf <- df[df$group == grp,]
  # Catch the warning where y is related to the log of negative numbers
  results <- tryCatch({
    mod1 <- lm(y ~ log(x), data = sampledf) 
    data.frame(group = grp, intercept = coef(mod1)[1], r2 = summary(mod1)$r.squared)
  }, warning = function(e) { 
    data.frame(group = grp, intercept = NA, r2 = NA)
  })
}))
```

So you return a `data.frame` with the coefficients when there's no warning, and one with `NA` when warnings (this way you also catch the warning, rather than the error and letting the warning go through). Also, `lapply` is generally preferred to `for` loops. And combining the results using `do.call("rbind", ...)` on the resulting list is probably more elegant.

Comment: Hey, thanks @hfty. This is exactly what I was looking for. I haven't used do.call before. I understand that for each row of the "df", you apply the function you define for each group then rbind the results together. What I'm fuzzy on is how to "translate" the do.call line to English. Is this right?: "For each value of "group", and therefore each row of the data.frame df, apply the defined function and rbind the results together in a data.frame"?  Basically, I just want to make sure I know exactly what's happening here so I could recreate it in a different situation...

Comment: @Nova I think you got it. You could separate the `lapply` to see what happens, but it's essentially a loop over `groups` which returns a list of data.frames. Then it's concatenated by the `do.call`. You can read more about it by doing `?do.call`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just used your method today for another task and it worked well. Awesome.

Comment: @Nova a sapply would also have helped here without doing the do.call ,                             final <- sapply(groups, function(grp) {
  sampledf <- df[df$group == grp,]
  # Catch the warning where y is related to the log of negative numbers
  results <- tryCatch({
    mod1 <- lm(y ~ log(x), data = sampledf) 
    data.frame(group = grp, intercept = coef(mod1)[1], r2 = summary(mod1)$r.squared)
  }, warning = function(e) { 
    data.frame(group = grp, intercept = NA, r2 = NA)
  })
})